# How can I sort this Data by ID?

Tags: odata

I'm trying to get the 10 latest records using this API call: https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataApi/OData/83131NED/TypedDataSet?$top=10

This results in 10 records, but the 10 earliest records. Instead, I want the latest records. So I thought I'd order by ID, but I can't get it to work.
For example:

```
https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataApi/OData/83131NED/TypedDataSet?$top=10&$orderby=ID desc
```

How come this is not working? What would I have to do to get the latest 10 records?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct. Looks like the endpoint doesn't support `$orderby`. It also doesn't support `$count`. Only `$top` and `$skip`.

I would try trial and error method to find the latest 10 items.

```
https://opendata.cbs.nl/ODataApi/OData/83131NED/TypedDataSet?$top=10&$skip=145338
```